# Fresh ubuntu set-up Golang + dep, dep ensure doesn't do anything

Tags: ubuntu, go, dep

I'm having an annoying problem and I can't find what the problem is. I'm quite new to Ubuntu/Golang/dep but I'm trying to understand how it works.

I have a source project, with the vendor files, when I run the command `dep ensure`, nothing happens, the cli just keeps running, no error message or any normal message, command is running for 30 minutes now and nothing happens.

For specific reasons I can't share anything about the project itself. For all I know, the files of the projects shouldn't be the problem.

The version of golang and dep are both the latest version.

The path to the go bin and dep bin has been set in the `.profile`, together with the exportating of the GOPATH path.

Comment: If you can't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's pretty unlikely we'll be able to help.

Comment: Also, it would be good to include the _actual_ version numbers, since "latest version" could become obsolete quickly (perhaps within hours).

Comment: You can try adding `-v` to `dep ensure` and maybe its output will help

Comment: Try removing the vendor directory and run again `dep ensure`